# How do I append text from a textbox to a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox, append

How can I get this `textarea` data into a `div`? I've tried `.append()` and `.val()` and `.text()` but it doesn't help me.

HTML:

```
<textarea id="Input" cols="50" rows="5">
    Insert text to be modified here
</textarea>
<div id="txt"></div>
<p><button id="append">Append</button></p>
```

jQuery:

```
$( "#append" ).click( function() {
    ( "#txt" ).append( function() {
        ( "Input" ).val();
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't worry so much about a DIV.  Look up how to work with INNERHTML.  That's probably more like what you want.

Comment: Ah! I remember that stuff! I tried using jQuery because writing out all that stuff got boring but I'll try it! Thanks :)

Comment: i didn't downvote your question, but i have a feeling without the rant it would have actually not received any... ;)

Comment: You can still use jquery if you want.  Just populate the contents of an INNER HTML tag.

Comment: at-webeno I'll remember that xD People can be asshats!
@durbnpoison Thanks :) I'll try that :)

Comment: The function you're passing to `.append()` gets the value, but it doesn't **return** it. Also, you're missing the `#` before `Input`.

Comment: @Barmar I see how you got all your rep now :) Thanks :D

Comment: @Barmar How do I make each append have a new line o great one?

Comment: I just modified the second code in my answer to show that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.append()` is for appending new HTML elements to the DOM, it's not for concatenating text. Use `.text()` to set the text of a DIV, and the `+` operator to concatenate strings.

```
$( "#append" ).click( function() {
    $( "#txt" ).text( function(i, oldtext) {
        return oldtext + $("#Input").val();
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/zcyymxk1/3/)

Actually, your code works after fixing some syntax errors. You're missing the `$` before some of the selectors, `#` before the `Input` ID, and the function you pass to `.append()` doesn't have a `return` statement. Fixing those, this works:

```
$( "#append" ).click( function() {
    $( "#txt" ).append( function() {
       return '<br>' + $( "#Input" ).val();
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/zcyymxk1/1/)

Comment: if I do `$('#txt').append($('#Input').val());`, then look at `txt`'s innerHTML, it shows a string, which isn't wrapped in a tag (such as `span`).  According to http://api.jquery.com/append/, `append()`'s content can be an "HTML string," which I assume wouldn't necessarily need HTML tags.  I haven't checked to see if `normalize()` is needed to remove empty text nodes, but `append` does look safe to use in this situation.  However, you're the expert!, and if you recommend using `append` for HTML *elements* only, I'll do so in my own code.

Comment: You're right, it does work that way. He had simpler errors in his code that were preventing it from working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) for this:

```
$("#append").click(function() {
    $("#txt").text($("#Input").val());
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/g93ns9gm/).

**Update**. Multiple appends:

```
$("#append").click(function() {
    $("#txt").text($("#txt").text() + " " + $("#Input").val());
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/g93ns9gm/1/).

Comment: This replaces the DIV's text content instead of appending to it.

Comment: @Regent one is generally thanking the other for when they help 'em... ;)

Comment: @Barmar after several readings of question it's still unclear whether OP wants to simply add `textarea` value to `div` or to really append it multiple times. Lets just give a chance for OP to clarify which way is correct.

Comment: Multiple appends will be done to keep a logged history I think :)